# LuaTeX's new_(node)inspection function

Tags: luatex, plain-tex

I was trying to test the [piTeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pitex) macros on LuaTeX (required), but the `base.ptxlua` macro file complained about not finding a mysterious "nodeinspector" module, required to setup some french spacing. Couldn't find it on the standard LuaTeX libraries, so I don't know what I'm missing.

---

Apparently, this module is missing. So, my problem (easily kludged by commenting out the code below) is that this module seems to apply some kerning to enable better French spacing, as follows.

```
require("nodeinspector")
new_inspection = nodeinspector.new_inspection

local french_highmarks = {
    string.byte("?"),
    string.byte("!"),
    string.byte(":"),
    string.byte(";"),
    }
local french_marks = {
    string.byte("?"),
    string.byte("!"),
    string.byte(":"),
    string.byte(";"),
    string.byte(","),
    string.byte("."),
    string.byte("("),
    string.byte("["),
    string.byte("{"),
    }

local function french_punctuation (head, ...)
    for _, glue in ipairs(arg) do
        if glue.id == 10 then
            head = node.remove(head, glue)
            node.free(glue)
        end
    end
    local kern = node.new(11, 1)
    kern.kern = tex.sp(".15em")
    node.insert_after(head, arg[1], kern)
end

pitex.callback.french_punctuation = new_inspection(
    french_punctuation,
  {{id = 37, _char = french_marks}, {true, id = 37, char = french_highmarks}},
    {{id = 10, subtype = 0}, {id = 11, subtype = 0}})

pitex.callback.register("kerning", "french_punctuation")
pitex.callback.original_kerning = node.kerning
pitex.callback.register("kerning", "original_kerning")
```

My guess is that this "module" is somewhat redundant, and it may be possible to reimplement this `new_inspection` function based on standard LuaTeX code. Any references to sources would be appreciated.

Comment: Hm, these are Paul Isamberts personal macros.  I don't even know why they are on CTAN.  What is it that you want to use from there?  Maybe there is a better way to do that.

Comment: I know... my question is whether this module was standard or not; in the latter case I shall move on to make another question...

Comment: A quick search turned up nothing so I don't think the `nodeinspector` module was ever on CTAN.